# Good programs for adding hardsubs

Tags: encoding, subtitles, mencoder

What are some good programs for adding hardsubs to an avi file? I've tried mencoder, and it's pretty good, but I can't figure out how to change the color of the subtitles. So I'm looking for another good program to use for adding hardsubs. I prefer programs that will run in OSX, but can also use Linux and Windows programs.

Answer (score 1):

HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded video transcoder, available for MacOS X, Linux and Windows.

http://handbrake.fr

Comment: This program is great. I doubt why this answer isn't accepted.  :)   By the way, now is 2018, do you happen to know other programs that is better?   Handbrake now supports batch job, but I still have to click to select the desired subtitle for each video.  Thanks.

Comment: @cppBeginner FFmpeg